# Get permanent residency in US while working remotely for a non-US company

Tags: usa, visa, greencard

I am planning on moving to the US (Hawaii to be specific if that matters) long-term with my family, but I can't figure out what the best way to get permanent residency for myself and my family is.

The legal situation is, I am a Swedish national, my wife is a Japanese national, and we have two small children who have Swedish/Japanese dual citizenship, and we currently reside in Japan.

I work remotely for a Swedish company, makes enough to support the whole family, and would like to continue working remotely for said company after moving to the US. I do not have a university education, if that matters.

I have read some of the IMHO confusing documentation on visas, and it seemed like a diversity program visa was my best shot, until I calculated that it's more likely that I will die of old age before I win the lottery.

What would you say is the best way for me and my family to get permanent residency (or the equivalent legal status where you can live and work indefinitely) in the US?

Comment: Basically you cannot unless you have a sponsor (family or employer), have lots of money to invest, are exceptionally successful in your field, or win the diversity visa lottery.  Another option would be asylum or refugee status, but you are not likely to qualify given the circumstances you've described.  The best way is therefore the lottery unless you want to change jobs.  Enter if you qualify.  I have met people who won it; it does happen.

Comment: Many winners don’t use their win, so the actual chances are about three times of the usual calculations.